# url rewrite for lighttpd - regex

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I would like to convert my urls to short ones without get parameters but for the first try I would reduce the regex to only one case:

There are many normal urls that should not be affected. The only case I want to rewrite the urls is the user profile page.

Currently they look like this:

```
www.dummy.com/index.php?user=USERNAME&id=USERID
```

Target scheme looks like this:

```
www.dummy.com/USERNAME/USERID
```

The usernames can contain mostly any character (without /) not just a-z/A-Z.

I was never really good at regexing and have no clue how to handle this problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

There won't be requests to a folder (www.dummy.com/folder/subfolder) but confirming that the userid is an integer value would be nice but is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?user=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will match either one of these URLs:

```
/abcd/123
/abcd/123/
/abcd456/6789
/abcd456/6789/
```

---

**EDIT:**

In LigthHttpd use this equivalent rule:

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/(\w+)/(\d+)/?(?:\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?user=$1&id=$2&$3" )
```

Comment: Thanks. But I use lighttpd. Are .htaccess files compatible to lighty? PS: Usernames can contain mostly any characters.

Comment: I will check light https docs but I think it should be supported. To support any character I will change the answer.

Comment: In `LightHTTPD` it will be: `url.rewrite = ( "^/(\w+)/(\d+)/?(?:\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?user=$1&id=$2&$3" )` [See this helpful guide](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/migratingfromapache)

Comment: thanks. I guess this is close enough for me to get where to go. Small modifications are no Problem.